# UIView alpha 0 but still receive touch events?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I am trying to hide a uiview but still have it receive touch events. I am setting the alpha to 0 like so:

```
mainView.alpha = 0.0
```

also I've tried setting this to true but it doesn't do anything

```
mainView.userInteractionEnabled = true
```

Trouble is it no longer receives touch events when I do this. How can I enable it to receive touch events but be effectively hidden?

Comment: You can do it, yes; but it would be better to rethink this. If the user can't see it, what sense does it make to ask the user to touch it? You should rethink the architecture of your touch handling.

Comment: This is expected. Hidden views or views with an alpha of 0 never receive events.

Comment: @matt This makes complete sense in some situations. For example, I have an app where the representation of an element needs to be small, but I want the user's interactive area to be bigger, but just invisible. The object representing the element, and the invisible one receiving events are different. So having a transparent object that captures user's input may make sense in some special situations, without having an architectural design problem.

Comment: @nbloqs Agreed, I've actually used transparent overlays for this. I didn't think of it when I made my comment.

Comment: This is the exact reason I did this was for having a larger touch area for a touch event than what the original element warranted.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Set your `UIView`'s `backgroundColor` to `UIColor.clear`.

```
mainView.backgroundColor = .clear
```

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to handle this:

1. The hard one - instead of setting alpha on the view, set it on all its subviews and make all the content in the view invisible (e.g. change background to clear color).
2. The easy one - let another view handle the events. Just add another transparent view with the same position and size (which is easy using constraints) which will handle the events.

By the way, if you check the documentation for method [hitTest:withEvent:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622469-hittest) which is used to handle touch events, it says that views with `alpha` lower than `0.01` won't receive touches.

Comment: yeh this works for the background but all the buttons are the same if I hide them they don't receive events. Trouble with number 2 is there is a search bar. Maybe I should make a new question and redo the way I'm handling touches?

Comment: @TylerRice Maybe try to extend you question with your view hierarchy and what you trying to accomplish? The reason why your code is not working is clear. If you extend your question, we can advice about the solution.

Comment: @Gobe It's still there, the link was broken though.

Answer (score 1):

Hide all subviews of the view and set the backgroundColor to UIColor clearColor

Answer (score -1):

Are you looking for a transparent view?

Just create a `TransparantView` sub class from UIView and copy below code. The view will be transparant, but still receive touches. You may need to change some code, because my code handles its subviews. The key is rewrite pointInside to meet your goals.

If you just want a transparent view, so other views under this transparent view can still get the touch events passed through the transparent view, you cannot add any subviews in transparentView.

The extended reading is to learn the responder chain.

```
@implementation TransparantView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    return self;
}

-(BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    for (UIView *view in self.subviews) {
        if (!view.hidden && view.alpha > 0 && view.userInteractionEnabled && [view pointInside:[self convertPoint:point toView:view] withEvent:event])
            return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
@end
```

UPDATE:

Seems iOS will not dispatch events to a view while its alpha is set to 0. However, the transparent view will have nothing on screen as if its alpha=0. I have updated the code to fix a bug

```
-(BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    for (UIView *view in self.subviews) {
        if (!view.hidden && view.alpha > 0 && view.userInteractionEnabled && [view pointInside:[self convertPoint:point toView:view] withEvent:event])
            return YES;
    }
    if (!self.hidden && self.alpha >= 0.0 && self.userInteractionEnabled) {
        return YES;
    } else
        return NO;
}
@end
```

Comment: how can I use this method in a view controller rather than a view?

Comment: I don't follow. It is just a sub class from a UIView and can meet you goals. Use it as a normal UIView, and you don't need to explicitly call any method. `pointInside` is a method that will be called by iOS when it needs to check if the view get a touch.

Comment: I have updated the answer, use the new code to try. The key is you need to understand how `pointInside` works.

Comment: This transparent view seems like a hacky way to do this so I wanted to try and track the touch events instead.. what do you think? Also I posted a new question since I'm unsure of how to achieve what I need to its at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30270526/disabling-user-interaction-for-parts-of-certain-views btw thanks for the help!

Comment: I am busy working so cannot answer the new question soon. I disagree its a hacky way, because that's what OOP does. You need to change the logic to meet your demands from time to time. With the code you can capture the touch events while the view is transparent. I feel you need to read the responder chain first. And another possibility is what you are trying to do is not recommended for iOS. There are principles while working with Views and controllers, and you don't want break it. If you truly need to break, then it is called hacky

Comment: ok I tried this.. always returning true but it won't receive touch events or even call the point inside method when alpha =0

Comment: Oh, I am sorry, seems iOS will not dispatch the event anymore while view.alpha = 0 . However, what I gives you is a transparent view, so even view.alpha=1, it will have nothing on screen , as if its alpha=0. Do you really need to set view.alpha=0? I don't see you have to, because the view is already transparent. answer updated.

Comment: I don't see how this makes the view transparent. Also I need to turn this on and off so it can't be an implementation I don't think

Comment: It is called transparent because you cannot see it on your screen. Turning it off on on depends on your logic. what you are asking is `How can I enable it to receive touch events but be effectively hidden?` As you can see, make the view hidden or alpha=0 will not let you recive touch events. I think the transparent view may fit your needs is it will get events, and I think it is equiverlant as 'effective hidden'

Comment: I believe it can solves the problem with minimum changes, because I had such issue back in time, and I share it with you. You do need to absorb and integreate it with your logic. Think out of the box, what you need is something on the screen acts as what you want it be, not something like I want the alpha is 0 and it must get events as well. Apple did not allow it. If you don't accept this way, then you may reconsider your architecture as @matt said.