# Possible Bug with UITapGestureRecognizer?

Tags: swift, xcode, uigesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am attempting to create a base view controller for all my view controllers to inherit from. This base view controller has a navigationController where the rightBarButtonItem is a button that displays a menu (menuButtonView) over the top of the entire view. The **menuButtonView** controls all of the functionality of the menu (presenting, dismissing, etc.)

I set the NavigationItem.rightBarButtonItem to this customized UIView called **menuButtonView** in the viewDidLoad:

```
let menuButtonView = NavigationMenuButton()
menuButtonView.delegate = self
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: menuButtonView)
```

The delegate is a simple protocol with one function to handle which menu item was selected. It basically just handles where to navigate to.

My **menuButtonView** is very simple, the class handles the menu presentation, dismissal, and actions on the background and menu items. When the **menuButtonView** is initialized it sets up a background view like so:

```
backgroundView = UIView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
backgroundView.alpha = 0.0
backgroundView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(backgroundSelected(_:))))
backgroundView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

It also sets up the menu items:

```
let logoutItem = NavigationMenuItem(title: "Log out", withSize: itemSize)
logoutItem.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.menuItemSelected(_:))))
logoutItem.tag = 2
self.openedFrame = CGRect(x....)
self.items.append(logoutItem)
```

When the menu button is selected, it runs this function:

```
func open() {

    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.view.addSubview(backgroundView)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
        self.backgroundView.alpha = 0.75

        for item in self.items {
            UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.view.addSubview(item)
            item.frame = item.openFrame
            item.alpha = 1.0
        }

    })

    self.isOpen = true

}
```

However, the bug is occurring with the background's and menuItems' tapGestureRecognizers... When I tap on the background, nothing happens, the `backgroundSelected` function is never triggered. But when I tap on a menuItem, both the `menuItemSelected` and `backgroundSelected` functions are triggered? There is nothing between initializing **menuButtonView** and calling the `open()` function that I do that would change the state of the background or menuButtonItems.

When a menuButtonItem is selected, I do call a protocol function that alerts the delegate that a menuButtonItem was selected so that the viewController can handle that action, but that shouldn't affect the tapGestureRecognizers.

After I open the menu, I even printed out the tapGestureRecognizers for each item and for the background and all of the logs matched what they should (each item has one recognizer with the target `menuButtonSelected` and the background has one recognizer with the target `backgroundSelected`). But when I actually tap the background, nothing happens, and when I tap a menu item, both the `menuButtonSelected` and `backgroundSelected` functions are triggered...

Could this be a bug in the UITapGestureRecognizer or am I not correctly setting the tapGestureRecognizers?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30269852/uiview-alpha-0-but-still-receive-touch-events.  You are setting an alpha of zero, which disables interaction with the background view.  Try setting the background color to `.clear`.

Comment: Ignore previous comment.  I didn't see the change in the `open()` method.